# Vue 2.0 SSR error page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implement ErrorPage vue component for my SSR application. I'm using boilerplate with

```
// server.js
...
const context = { url: req.url };
const stream = renderer.renderToStream(context);

// If an error occurs while rendering
stream.on('error', (error) => {
  var app = new Vue({
    template: '<div>Error page</div>'
  });

  errRenderer.renderToString(app, function (error, html) {
    return res
      .status(500)
      .send(html);
  });
});
```

I'm aware that this is not super pretty, but is there another way of handling that? Ideally I would love to just load an external Vue component and send it to the browser.

Comment: did you get any solution ?